# "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare link()" при объявлении функции link

Tags: php

```
function link(){
    echo "<a href='http://clv.hol.es'>Онлай игра</a>";
}
```

Ошибка:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare link()

Answer (score 2):

Потому что есть уже [функция](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.link.php) с таким именем в самом PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Функция [link()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.link.php) в PHP создает ссылки, на файлы там, например, и т.д., т.е. она уже задекларирована/

Переименуйте свою функцию в `mylink()`, например, и всё замечательно заработает. Хотя нет, вру. Если еще смените двойные кавычки на одинарные, и наоборот - вот тогда точно заработает.

Answer (score 0):

Вы, наверное, в цикле несколько раз вызываете файл с функцией. Вызывайте просто функцию, а файл вызовите выше цикла один раз.

Comment: Вот полный код:
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
    <title>Функции</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    link(); 
    function square($a)
    {
    $result = $a*$a;
    echo $result;
    }
    $e = 325;
    echo "Квадрат $e равен - ";
    square(325);
    function link()
    {
    echo "<a href='http://clv.hol.es'>Онлай игра</a>";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Как это?? нет вроде..

Comment: Ок, ошиблась.

Comment: У меня первая функция работает! А вот вторая фукция, где я хочу указать ссылку, не работает, выдает ошибку! Я не могу исправить! Почему так происходит?

Comment: Переименуйте функцию link хотя бы в links, как сказано выше. Она уже присутствует в PHP.

Comment: Понял! ща попробую..